# How to select only one record for each primary key item from joined table?

Tags: java, oracle

I have two tables called Hotels and Description. Description table contains descriptions of each hotel.

- In hotels table, id and city_id together form the primary key (id itself is not a primary key)
- On description table, each hotel can have upto 8 description types (general, location, rooms, exterior, pleasenote, inclusive, lobby)

I want to update master table using Hotel table and Description table. For each record in Hotel table,I should insert exactly one row to the master table. When I perform left outer join each records in the Hotel table produces multiple records since one hotel has 0 or more description types.

I want to pick just one description for each hotel from Description table and it is not the first description always. (If it was, I could use [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group)). Instead I have a priority order for description types. First I need to check whether there is a 'general' description. If there is, then that should be the description for the master table and remaining description for the hotel should be skipped. If 'general' description type is not available, then I want to check whether 'location' description type is available and so on.

I tried to write the Oracle SQL query for this, it doesn't do exactly what I want.

[image]

Following is the query that I used to join two tables (multiple rows for each hotel). How can I filter out just one row for each hotel, while adhering to above guidelines?

Code:

```
    SELECT HOTEL_DETAILS.*,
    Description.Desc_type,
    Description.description
    FROM
     (SELECT Hotel.id,
             Hotel.city_id,
             Hotel.hotel_name,         
             City.country_code
           FROM Hotel
           LEFT OUTER JOIN City
           ON Hotel.city_id=City.city_id
     ) HOTEL_DETAILS
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Description
   ON HOTEL_DETAILS.id    =Description.id
   AND HOTEL_DETAILS.city_id    = Description.city_id
```

I tried to use use DECODE function, but seems like it doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT dtl.id,
           dtl.city_id,
           dtl.hotel_name,
           dtl.country_code,
           min(dsc.desc_type)   KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE dsc.desc_type WHEN 'general' THEN 1 WHEN 'location' THEN 2 WHEN 'rooms' THEN 3 WHEN 'lobby' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END) desc_type,
           min(dsc.description) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE dsc.desc_type WHEN 'general' THEN 1 WHEN 'location' THEN 2 WHEN 'rooms' THEN 3 WHEN 'lobby' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END) description
      FROM (SELECT htl.id,
                   htl.city_id,
                   htl.hotel_name,         
                   cty.country_code
              FROM hotel htl
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN city cty
                     ON (htl.city_id = cty.city_id)) dtl
           LEFT OUTER JOIN dsc
             ON (   dtl.id = dsc.id
                AND dtl.city_id = dsc.city_id)
    GROUP BY dtl.id,
             dtl.city_id,
             dtl.hotel_name,
             dtl.country_code,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **CASE** expression in the sql to give an order for the description types, sort by this order and then use the link you mentioned to get the first in the group. Something like below;

```
SELECT HOTEL_DETAILS.*,
    CASE Description.Desc_type
      WHEN 'general' THEN 0
      WHEN 'location' THEN 1
      WHEN 'rooms' THEN 2
      WHEN 'lobby' THEN 3
      ELSE 99 
    END desc_order,
    Description.description
    FROM
     (SELECT Hotel.id,
             Hotel.city_id,
             Hotel.hotel_name,         
             City.country_code
           FROM Hotel
           LEFT OUTER JOIN City
           ON Hotel.city_id=City.city_id
     ) HOTEL_DETAILS
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Description
   ON HOTEL_DETAILS.id    =Description.id
   AND HOTEL_DETAILS.city_id    = Description.city_id
   ORDER BY HOTEL_DETAILS.id, HOTEL_DETAILS.city_id, desc_order
```